# Iteratively filter dataframe with varying condition

Tags: r, purrr

I want to create many dataframes based on a filtering condition. I have recently tried to improve my skill with R, and functional programming approaches in particular.

The reprex below shows a copy/paste method of obtaining what I want --- a variety of dataframes to be analyzed after some filtering conditions have been applied based on a column within the dataframe. Obviously, not practical for arbitrarily many filtering conditions.

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(a = rnorm(5000, mean = 500, sd = 20),
            b = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 5000/4))

thresholds = c(400, 450, 500, 550)


df_400 = df %>% filter(a < 400)
df_450 = df %>% filter(a < 450)
df_500 = df %>% filter(a < 500)
df_550 = df %>% filter(a < 550)
```

I have tried variations using `map2`, but I'm not sure how to vary over the rows of the dataframe and also base a condition on it. I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: This can do it `map(thresholds, ~df %>% filter(a < .x))`

Comment: And using lapply do it with this one `lapply(thresholds, function(x){df[df[["a"]] < x, ]})`

Comment: I see I was misunderstanding the ~notation in my attempts at solving this. Both answers are great. Feel free to make an official 'answer' and I'll accept it, as it was consistent with tidy syntax. Either way I'll close this out later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I put in my comment, this is the answer using base r and dplyr approach.

**dplyr**

`map(thresholds, ~df %>% filter(a < .x))`

**base r**

`lapply(thresholds, function(x){df[df[["a"]] < x, ]})`

Answer (score 1):

One way could be:

```
lapply(thresholds, function(x) filter(df, a < x))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 0 x 2
# … with 2 variables: a <dbl>, b <chr>

[[2]]
# A tibble: 22 x 2
       a b    
   <dbl> <chr>
 1  440. c    
 2  448. c    
 3  445. d    
 4  443. b    
 5  443. a    
 6  448. d    
 7  435. a    
 8  438. b    
 9  447. c    
10  444. c    
# … with 12 more rows
```

If you want to keep it completely in the terms of `tidyverse`, then look at the nice comment from @Johan Rosa.